# Distribution function of a biased estimator

Tags: self-study, inference, expected-value, unbiased-estimator, mse

$f(y) = ay^{a-1}/θ^a,      0<y<θ$

$ \hat{\Theta} = max(Y_1, Y_2, . . . , Y_n).$

How do I find the $E[\hat{\Theta}]$ ?

I'm trying to show that it's a biased estimator, then I'm going to find an unbiased version and derive MSE.

Comment: Find the CDF of the maximum.  (It's an easy calculation.)

Comment: Add the self study tag.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I've added the tag, thanks I'm new here.

Comment: @whuber
I know I need the distribution function of theta_hat but I don't know what it is. How would I go about finding the CDF? I'm sorry if these are really basic, dumb questions, I'm new to mathematical statistics and having only done applied statistics in my field (psychology) I get easily confused.

Comment: Independence and the definition of maximum give $$\eqalign{\Pr(\max(\{Y_i\})\le y)&=\Pr(Y_1\le y,\, Y_2\le y,\,\ldots Y_n\le y)\\ &= \Pr(Y_1\le y)\Pr(Y_2\le y)\cdots \Pr(Y_n\le y)\\ &= F(y)^n}$$ where $F$ is the common CDF of all the $Y_i.$ Also observe that since $f(y)\mathrm{d}y$ is a function of $y/\theta,$ $\theta$ is a scale factor, whence the answer is directly proportional to $\theta.$ You may as well take $\theta=1,$ for which it is clear that $F(y)=y^a.$

Comment: While this is a simple algebraic problem, it's clear that it must be biased just from general reasoning.  The distribution is continuous, and the observations are bounded above by $\theta$, so *every* observation is $<\theta$ with probability 1. Therefore the maximum is  $<\theta$ with probability 1. Therefore the mean of the distribution of the maximum is  $<\theta$.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the way I like to explain this to my class.

If the $Y_i$ represent the heights of a group of people, then $\hat\theta$ is the height of the tallest person. If the tallest person can walk through a door without hitting his head, then so can everybody in the group! Hopefully you agree with the logic behind this. Mathematically, this is equivalent to saying
$$P(\hat\theta \leq y) = P(\text{all of the $Y_i \leq y$}) = P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n[Y_i \leq y]\right)$$
From here the calculation is easy! (Use independence)